# Rearrange rows in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe as follows

```
    DIASEMANA   DATAOCORRENCIA  TOTAL
0   Domingo 2018-01-07  148
1   Domingo 2018-01-14  126
2   Domingo 2018-01-21  111
3   Domingo 2018-01-28  130
4   Domingo 2018-02-04  120
... ... ... ...
360 Terca   2018-11-27  228
361 Terca   2018-12-04  179
362 Terca   2018-12-11  121
363 Terca   2018-12-18  125
364 Terca   2018-12-25  60
```

And I want to rearrange by placing the lines in the following order of the DAYWEEK column: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday.

I tried to use reindex but I have around 52 values ​​for each day of the week.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to make sure your date is of datetime type, then you can extract `day_of_week` and sort:

```
df['DATAOCORRENCIA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATAOCORRENCIA'])
df['day_of_week'] = df.DATAOCORRENCIA.dt.dayofweek
df = df.sort_values('day_of_week')
```